# Extensive planning, stringent testing and uncompromising quality control gives our customers confidence in our products. Give or gives?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is it 'give' or 'gives' in this context? The 'give' follows a list of singular items. I would have thought it would only be 'give' if the listed items are plural but a colleague has brought it to my attention.

e.g. '...stringent testing and uncompromising quality controls give our customers...'

e.g. '...stringent testing and uncompromising quality control gives our customers...'

Answer (score 2):

If you're saying that each one of the items gives confidence, then use plural agreement:

- ...stringent testing and uncompromising quality controls **give** our customers....

If you're saying that the confidence comes from the gestalt of the three items together, use singular agreement:

- ...stringent testing and uncompromising quality controls **gives** our customers....

You can consider this a generalisation of the treatment of compound nouns:

> ***Rule 4***. As a general rule, use a plural verb with two or more subjects when they are connected by *and*.
>
> > ***Example:*** A car and a bike are my means of transportation.
>
> But note these exceptions:
>
> > ***Exceptions:***
> >
> > *Breaking and entering is against the law.*
> >
> > *The bed and breakfast was charming.*
>
> In those sentences, *breaking and entering* and *bed and breakfast* are compound nouns.
>
> [- grammarbook.com](https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)

Comment: Quite right. When interpreting it as a gestalt, it would be the equivalent of prefacing the list with *the combination of*.

Answer (score 0):

A subject of the form *A, B and C* is definitely plural, so you have to use *give* here. Perhaps you are confusing this with a sentence such as:

> Our policy of extensive planning, stringent testing and uncompromising
>   quality control gives our customers confidence in our products.

Here the subject, *our policy*, is singular.

Native English speakers are often sloppy where such distinctions are in play, so don't assume that everything you read is correct.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't quite figure out why. As a native English speaker, I'm on the side of those constantly trying to improve, I'd always rather be corrected!

Answer (score -1):

Give. If you used "or" instead of "and" could have been gives.